# SharePoint Online - Search File Name by middle characters

Tags: search, sharepoint

We have files in  a SharePoint Online library's that got migrated from an old network drive, unfortunately all the files have names like "ReportOnTheMexicoArea20010101.doc".  If a user wanted to find that exact file they may search for "Mexico" but that will not return this file as its characters within a string, is there any custom query or trick to search characters in the middle of a file name?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not support suffix wildcard search, it only support for prefix matching.When you use words in a free-text KQL query, Search in SharePoint returns results based on exact matches of your words with the terms stored in the full-text index. You can use just a part of a word, from the beginning of the word, by using the wildcard operator (*) to enable prefix matching. In prefix matching, Search in SharePoint matches results with terms that contain the word followed by zero or more characters.

For example: *Report**

I would suggest you expand your approach for tagging your documents. I would suggest you use SharePoint metadata to tag your documents rather than just creating a title.